# coping contents of the const char* type variable caused unexpected result

Tags: c++, pointers

```
const char* mTest1; /*This variable has been assigned value before and 
                      the print out indicates it is correct.*/
char* mTest2;

if(mTest1 != NULL){
   mTest2 = new char[strlen(mTest1) +1]{};
   std::copy(mTest1, mTest1 + strlen(mTest1), mTest2);
   printf("\n===== mTest1 is: %s =============", mTest1);
   printf("\n===== mTest2 is: %s =============", mTest2);    
}
```

I would expect both of these two printf should print out the same result.

However, the result is not correct.

```
===== mTest1 is: c52b =============
===== mTest2 is: c52bZZZZ@m�� =============
```

Is there any wrong approach I've taken in coping the contents to mTest2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add teminating symbol '\0' at the end of the string after copying it:

```
const char* mTest1; /*This variable has been assigned value before and 
                      the print out indicates it is correct.*/
char* mTest2;

if(mTest1 != NULL){
   mTest2 = new char[strlen(mTest1) +1]{};
   std::copy(mTest1, mTest1 + strlen(mTest1), mTest2);
   mTest2[strlen(mTest1)] = '\0';
   printf("\n===== mTest1 is: %s =============", mTest1);
   printf("\n===== mTest2 is: %s =============", mTest2);    
}
```

When you work with c-style strings (char *), you always should remember about terminating symbols. As usual, copying operators copy only content of the string, and not terminating symbol, because it's signal for them to stop.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expeert in `c++`, but from this line

```
std::copy(mTest1, mTest1 + strlen(mTest1), mTest2);
```

It looks like you're missing to copy the null terminator in `mTest2`. Maybe you can try

```
 std::copy(mTest1, mTest1 + strlen(mTest1) + 1 , mTest2);
```

Or, you can add that manually, after copying the string, using

```
mTest2[strlen(mTest1)] = '\0';
```